# fit pdf file into web view in iOS

Tags: html, ios, iphone, pdf, uiwebview

I want to show pdf file into my web view.Webview may contains only text or text+pdf,text+images,etc.

It is working fine for me but **when the web view has pdf then its height & width are not fit as per web view frame. I have scroll horizontally & vertically to see it. Also if pdf has multipage then its height is not adjust.**

**Try 1**

```
web.scalesPageToFit=YES;
```

problem: All content is very small & looks very ugly.

**Try 2**

```
[web setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[web setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

Problem: Not working

**Try 3**

```
[web loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><meta name='viewport' content='width:05px; initial-scale=0.5; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;'/></head>
<body><div style='font-size:14px; font-family:Opensans';>
<object style='width:100%; height:100%' type='application/pdf' data='http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/econcs/pubs/online.pdf'></object><p>ab sofort!</p></div>
</body></html>"] baseURL:nil];
```

Problem: Not working, pdf is only shows half part.

**Try 4**

```
[web_large loadHTMLString:@"<object style='width:620px; height:950px' type='application/pdf' data='http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/econcs/pubs/online.pdf'></object><p>ab sofort!</p>\n" baseURL:nil];
```

Problem: width is scrollable horizontally & height is fixed so not working for multi page pdf.

**Thanks**

**Any answer please**

Comment: @AvijitNagare, this is not a duplicate question! My issue is fit pdf document in webview